# Referencing nested JSON Objects in Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object, datatables

I have the following JSON:

```
[
       {
       "id":"78",
        "packaging": "0",
        "created_at": "2013-01-28 13:46:41",
        "updated_at": "2013-01-28 13:46:41",
        "Clients": {
                      "id": "6",
                      "Name": "Some Name",
                      "Address": "0000000",
                      "Email":"email@somedomain.com"
           }
     },
     {
       "id":"79",
        "packaging": "0",
        "created_at": "2013-01-28 13:46:41",
        "updated_at": "2013-01-28 13:46:41",
        "Clients": {
                      "id": "9",
                      "Name": "Some Other Name",
                      "Address": "0000001",
                      "Email":"email@someotherdomain.com"
           }
     }
]
```

I have verified that it is valid JSON on Jsonlint.com.

I have managed to reference the unnested data as below:

```
    {"sTitle":"Id","mData":"id"},
    {"sTitle":"Created At","mData":"created_at"},
    {"sTitle":"Updated At.","mData":"updated_at"},
```

Now I want to be able to reference the Clients' Name on datatables.

How do I do this using `mData`?

Comment: did you trying using the conventional `"Clients.Name"`?

Comment: Yes dot notation.Trying that right away. Thanks.

Comment: The conventional "Clients.Name" works. Thank you man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
{"sTitle":"Client ID","mData":"Clients.id"},
{"sTitle":"Client Name","mData":"Clients.Name"},
{"sTitle":"Client Address","mData":"Clients.Address"}
```